# It says Incorrect syntax near ',' when I try to insert an item into my database?

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-express

Code :

```
Private m_cn As New SqlConnection
Private m_DA As SqlDataAdapter
Private m_CB As SqlCommandBuilder
Private m_DataTable As New DataTable
Private m_intRowPosition As Integer = 0

Private Sub InsertDatabaseItem_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    m_cn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=My-PC\SQLSERVEREXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ConvienienceProducts;Integrated Security=True"

    m_cn.Open()
    m_DA = New SqlDataAdapter("Select * From ProductIndex", m_cn)
    m_CB = New SqlCommandBuilder(m_DA)
End Sub

Private Sub btnOK_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOK.Click
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(("INSERT INTO ProductIndex VALUES(" &
                              txtID.Text & "," &
                              txtName.Text & "," &
                              txtPrice.Text & "," &
                              txtDesc.Text & ")"), m_cn)

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    MsgBox("Success....", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "SUCCESS")

    Me.Hide()

    txtID.Clear()
    txtName.Clear()
    txtPrice.Clear()
    txtDesc.Clear()

    m_cn.Close()
    m_cn.Dispose()
End Sub

Private Sub btnCancel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Click
    Me.Hide()
End Sub
```

This is the error message :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You code should be using [`parameters`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx).  Try this:

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(("INSERT INTO ProductIndex VALUES(" &
                          "@ID," &
                          "@Name," &
                          "@Price," &
                          "@Desc)"), m_cn)

cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Char)
cmd.Parameters("@ID").Value = txtID.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.Char)
cmd.Parameters("@Name").Value = txtName.Text   
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Price",  SqlDbType.Char)
cmd.Parameters("@Price").Value = txtPrice.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Desc",  SqlDbType.Char)
cmd.Parameters("@Desc").Value = txtDesc.Text
```

The types are probably wrong (especially `Price`, and probably `ID`), but as you know what they are, and I don't, you can easily correct them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your string values in single quotes

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(("INSERT INTO ProductIndex VALUES('" & txtID.Text & "',
```

Hard to see but there is a single quote just before and after the double quotes surrounding your variables.

I have answered your particular question but you should be using parameters